# Configuring custom taskExecutor in spring integration <int-jms:inbound-gateway>

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

Currently, I am looking to configure custom task executor i.e. workmanager to spring's .  I have tried to configure using task-executor attribute, but it seems it doesn't support it.
Reasson here, I want to do delegate it to server's thread management than using Spring's default task executor.  Below is the sample configuration -

```
<jms:inbound-gateway request-destination="getQueue" 
        request-channel="inputChannel" 
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
        error-channel="errorChannel" concurrent-consumers="10"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager"  
        reply-delivery-persistent="false" reply-time-to-live="30000" explicit-qos-enabled-for-replies="true"
        />

I have tried to plug the taskExecutor as below, but it doesn't seems to be working.  I am not sure if there is anything wrong with it?  Do I need to provide "messageListener" too with container?  However, I have tried hooking messageListener as well i.e. using ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener, but that too didn't work.  Here issue is, it is not picking/reading the messages from "destination".

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
      <property name="workManagerName" value="wm/default" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />

<jms:inbound-gateway request-channel="inputChannel" error-channel="errorChannel" container="channelContainer"/>

<bean id="channelContainer"
class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
<property name="destination" ref="getQueue" />
<property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
<property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
<property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
</bean>

<int:chain input-channel="inputChannel">
     <int:transformer method="..." ref="messageTransformer" />
     <int:claim-check-in message-store="messageStore"/>
     <int:header-enricher>
         <int:header name="..." expression="payload" />
     </int:header-enricher>
     <int:claim-check-out message-store="messageStore"/>
     <int:transformer method="..." ref="requestObjectConverter" />
     <int:service-activator method="..." ref="...." />
     <int:transformer method="..." ref="responseObjectConverter" />
     <int:transformer method="...." ref="messageTransformer" />
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="errorChannel">
      <int:transformer method="..." ref="errorTransformer" />
</int:chain>

<bean id="errorTransformer" class="....">
    ......
    <property name="messageStore" ref="messageStore"></property>
    ......
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wire up a `<bean/>` of type `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and provide it to the gateway via the `container` attribute...

```
<jms:inbound-gateway id="gatewayWithContainerReference"
                     container="messageListenerContainer"
                     request-channel="requestChannel" />

<bean id="messageListenerContainer" 
       class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="testConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destinationName" value="testDestination"/>
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="workManagerTE" />
    ...
</bean>
```

Note that certain JMS-related attributes go on the container, not directly on the gateway. Other attributes remain on the gateway.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I have tried given configuration already... but somehow it wasn't working i.e. wasn't receiving the messages...  Do we need to configure "messageListener" as well on container?

Comment: As you can see, it's not easy to read configuration in comments; please delete them and edit your question instead and I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi Gary... I have deleted the comments and edited the question itself as suggested.  Please have a look and let me know your comments.  Here issue is, mentioned configuration (in edited question) isn't really reading/picking the messages from destination.

Comment: `>Do we need to configure "messageListener" as well on container?`  No; the gateway sets itself as the listener (you will see a warning log if the container already has one when it is replaced). The configuration looks ok; I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` to see what's going on.

Comment: ok.. I am not still able to get the root cause of it... I just wanted to know since I am trying to use "default" work manager here, do we need to reconfigure its properties?  Would specifying "coucurrentConsumers" property on continer hurt when you are actually using server's workmanager?

Comment: The `concurrentConsumers` is simply used to ask the work manager for that number of threads. Post the debug log someplace like a github gist, if you like, and I'll take a look. Perhaps you could first debug out of the container, using a stand-along task executor.

Comment: ok... so I have made some progress here... Mentioned configuration with DefaultMessageListenerContainer with spring's own taskexecutor works fine i.e. reads and processes messages as expected.  But it doesn't work as expected moment I plug custom taskExecutor i.e. Webshpere's work manager here.  It also doesn't work as expected even when I plug external transactionManager i.e. WebSphere's transaction manager here.  I am not sure what the root cause is.  And I didn't really find something useful from logs either.

Comment: Perhaps some issue with the WM configuration? Next step is to try using it in your app outside of JMS. If that works then it's weird. DEBUG/TRACE logging produces copious logs from the DMLC; if you see no activity it implies we don't get a thread from the WM. A thread dump would confirm that.

Comment: I am using "default" WM that comes with Websphere 8.5... I have tried using another WM available with this version i.e. AsyncRequestDispatcherWorkManager...  don't see anything wrong with configuration...  there are few parameters that we may tune i.e. min/max no. of threds...  So I feel, we are not getting a thread from the WM... not too sure... Let me know if you have any inputs specific to WM configuration or using with Spring gateways...

Comment: Or do we need to register the workmanager explicitly as a resource with application?

Comment: It's been many years since I worked with WebSphere so I can't help - have you looked at the [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-task-executor-types) ?

Comment: ok... yes, I did have a look at given documentation before... anyways, I am debugging it further...  thanks for inputs!

Comment: Hi Gary...  Here, I have seen "workManager" processing the requests in logs but after restarting the server/app...  any clue what could be the reason here?

Comment: Hi Gary...  I think, I have got it working... It was resolved after setting "cacheLevelName" to "CACHE_CONNECTION" on container... Earlier, it was failing while setting up the listener itself and hence not consuming the messages...  Anyways, happy about it...  But I was just wondering whether inbound gateway sets this property internally on container?